# unfortunately app has stopped in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

Hi am new to Android App development.I am getting message in AVD like - unfortunately has stopped ,please help me to solve this error...

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.p.play;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
private static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;

private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
private TextView selelctedFile = null;
private SeekBar seekbar = null;
private MediaPlayer player = null;
private ImageButton playButton = null;
private ImageButton prevButton = null;
private ImageButton nextButton = null;

private boolean isStarted = true;
private String currentFile = "";
private boolean isMoveingSeekBar = false;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                updatePosition();
        }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

selelctedFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
prevButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev);
nextButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

player = new MediaPlayer();

player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if(null != cursor)
{
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, cursor);

        setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        prevButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
}
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

        currentFile = (String) view.getTag();

        startPlay(currentFile);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();

        player = null;
}

private void startPlay(String file) {
        Log.i("Selected: ", file);

        selelctedFile.setText(file);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);

        player.stop();
        player.reset();

        try {
                player.setDataSource(file);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

        updatePosition();

        isStarted = true;
}

private void stopPlay() {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);

        isStarted = false;
}

private void updatePosition(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

        seekbar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

        handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
}

private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
                super(context, layout, c, 
                                new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                                new int[] { R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration });
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
                TextView duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

                name.setText(cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

                title.setText(cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

                long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

                double durationInMin = ((double)durationInMs/1000.0)/60.0;

                durationInMin = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue(); 

                duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

                view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);

                bindView(v, context, cursor);

                return v;
        }
}

private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                        case R.id.play:
                        {
                                if(player.isPlaying())
                                {
                                      handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                                        player.pause();
                         playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        if(isStarted)
                                        {
                                                player.start();
                 playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

                                                updatePosition();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                startPlay(currentFile);
                                        }
                                }

                                break;
                        }
                        case R.id.next:
                        {
                                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                                if(seekto > player.getDuration())
                                        seekto = player.getDuration();

                                player.pause();
                                player.seekTo(seekto);
                                player.start();

                                break;
                        }
                        case R.id.prev:
                        {
                                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;

                                if(seekto < 0)
                                        seekto = 0;

                                player.pause();
                                player.seekTo(seekto);
                                player.start();

                                break;
                        }
                }
        }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlay();
        }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // returning false will call the OnCompletionListener
                return false;
        }
};

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isMoveingSeekBar = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isMoveingSeekBar = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                if(isMoveingSeekBar)
                {
                        player.seekTo(progress);

                        Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener","onProgressChanged");
                }
        }
};
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/dnp_1">

<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/displayname"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/selectedfile"
            android:text="Not file selected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="middle"/>

<ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light"
    android:padding="10dip">


    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light">

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/prev"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"/>

    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/duration"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.p.play"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.p.play.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
       android:name=".MediaCursorAdapter"
       android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity> 
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is Logcat

```
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): Process: com.p.play, PID: 1125
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        activity ComponentInfo{com.p.play/com.p.play.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException:  Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=1125, uid=10052 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=1125, uid=10052 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.p.play.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-15 03:15:00.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     ... 11 more
```

Please help me.And thanks in advance...

Comment: What are you doing when the application crashes? What does the logcat say? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: whenever post your query,then do post the logcat please...

Comment: possible duplicate of [android 4.4 video from camera gives security Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245021/android-4-4-video-from-camera-gives-security-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permission in your Android application's AndroidManifest file.
i.e `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
Just add this line in manifest file of your project

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

just above the application tag

Comment: So, you should mark the answer as "accepted answer" so the others know the problem is solved. And if the answer appears good to you, you can also +1 it !